# Using Express and Axios, Axios will not recognize PUT Requests

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, axios, request

I have dumbed down my use case to a simple test, in which I click a button and an UPDATE put request is sent using an axios API. **Three other request methods-- post, get, and delete, all work properly and are recognized.** My PUT method, however, gives a 404 Not Found error, as though I havent established the method with express in my server.

This is the code for the request, triggered by this event handler (for the button):

```
const handleUpdate = async (e, id) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // navigate(`/restaurants/${id}/update`);
        //update test
        try {
            const updatedRestaurant = await RestaurantFinder.put(`/${id}`, {
                name: "taco bell",
                location: "dogtown",
                price_range: "2"
              });
              console.log(updatedRestaurant);
              navigate("/");
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      };
```

This is the api's instantiation:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants"
    }
);
```

This is the request in Express. Note that the first log "does this exist???" is never displayed. The address for the put request to "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/id" is never found.

```
//UPDATE a restaurant
app.put("/api/v1/restaurants/:id"), async (req, res) => {
    console.log("does this exist???");
    try {
        const results = await db.query(
          "UPDATE restaurants SET name = $1, location = $2, price_range = $3 where id = $4 returning *",
          [req.body.name, req.body.location, req.body.price_range, req.params.id]
        );
    
        res.status(200).json({
          status: "succes",
          data: {
            restaurant: results.rows[0],
          },
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(req.params.id);
      console.log(req.body);
};
```

I have pored over StackOverflow for answers, I think I've viewed over 50 posts at this point. This is something that should be so simple, and yet I can't find a single answer for it or see where it's happening to anyone else.

If anyone could please help walk me through what is going wrong, I would be so grateful!

Edit 1 @Stephen:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors(
  {
  methods: ["POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT"]
}
));
app.use(express.json());
```

So i changed it to this with no luck. Originally i was just using cors(), and my understanding is that it defaults to allowing a put method.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server allow the `put` method? Perhaps your server only allows the others in the access-control-allow-methods field.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

For testing over http, make sure both of these are set by your server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check this right now and get back to you!

Comment: post the request and response headers from your dev console network call.  cross out your cookies though.

Comment: I'll do that now. i just responded to you by editing my post. This is my first stackoverflow post, and I hope i did that correctly...

Comment: @outoftheblue,  What does your console indicate? no response, hang, or error message?

Comment: On each update prompt, it sends two requests:
Request URL: http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/6
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:3001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

AND

Request URL: http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/6
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Also, if you change it to `post`, it works?

Comment: It indicates an error: xhr.js:210 PUT http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/6 404 (Not Found)

Comment: add OPTIONS to your allowed methods.

Comment: there is a post method with the same dynamic-id url, used for adding a restaurant, and that indeed does work correctly.

Comment: I added OPTIONS, and it still does not work. methods: ["POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS"]

Comment: This is probably a combination of using a different port than your web app is on, not including options in the allowed methods header, and the allow-host header.  set the allowed hosts to '*' while  using http to rule that out.

Comment: also put a log message outside your `put` function to ensure it is getting loaded.

Comment: `RestaurantFinder` where is that coming from? How did your import it?

Comment: What I dont understand is that simple "cors()" instantiation should default to allowing all origins and those methods. I don't think those settings are the answer.

Comment: RestaurantFinder is the axios instance posted in the second code block in my post. It is imported like so: import RestaurantFinder from "../apis/RestaurantFinder";

Comment: I also just want to say again, thank you for all the time you're putting on this. It is appreciated and educational!

Comment: I think this is the most confusing and debilitating thing I've encountered in all of computer science.

Comment: check out my answer below... that was the only problem. a parenthesis misplaced. fooled us both...

Comment: so it should have had a syntax error,, and a debug statement outside the method would not have printed, yes?

Comment: Good point. Thank you.